# Spelling for the spoken contraction of "on the"

Tags: contractions, connected-speech

When "on the" is spoken very fast they are connected, contracted, forming a connected-speech.

Even **knowing that this contraction doesn't exist** in English, how could it be written to reflect the spoken contraction?

Using other **informal** contractions like "otta", "shoulda", "kinda", "sorta", I ended up on these:

- ona
- onn'a
- onna

Answer (score 1):

None of "otta", "shoulda", "kinda", or "sorta" are standard English, althoguh some of them are becoming more commonly used. To the best of my knowledge, there is no standard English contraction for “on the”.

It might occur in dialog when representing rapid informal speech. If it does, there is no standard agreed spelling for it.

Comment: Per my comment above, we Brits have the highly-specific "rustic Northern English" usage ***on't***. But whereas "otta", "shoulda", "kinda", or "sorta" all just reflect "non-specific relaxed speech", that British version is very "region-specific", so it implies everything else you might associate with the relevant location, age group, sociolinguistic class, etc. The orthography is pretty "standard" though.

Comment: The question doesn't assume they are standard English, at all. It is exactly the opposite. It asks how people would write it informally to **reflect the spoken** language.